# Efficiently compute the modulo of the sum of two numbers

Tags: c, math, modulo, number-theory

I have three `N`-bit numbers, `A`, `B`, and `C`.  I cannot easily calculate `(A + B) % C` but I can easily calculate `A % C` and `B % C`.  If the modulo operation is unsigned and I know ahead of time that `A + B` does not wrap around `N` bits then I can instead calculate `((A % C) + (B % C)) % C`.  However, is it possible to do anything for the cases where the modulo operation is signed or the addition of `A` and `B` might lead to a wrap-around.

It looks like there might be some confusion as to why `((A % C) + (B % C)) % C` cannot be relied upon to always work.  Here is an unsigned example:

```
unsigned A = 0x1U;
unsigned B = 0xFFFFFFFFU;
unsigned C = 0x3U;
((A % C) + (B % C)) % C == 0x1U but (A + B) % C == 0x0U
```

Here is a signed example:

```
int A = 0x1;
int B = 0xE27F9803;
int C = 0x3U;
((A % C) + (B % C)) % C == 0x1U but (A + B) % C == -2
```

Comment: I'm under the impression that your formula works for signed numbers as well as for unsigned ones. Could someone please provide a counter example otherwise?

Comment: Please provide an actual example.

Comment: Also, there are many varied implementation of mod(). For example in JavaScript, -10 % 3 = -1. Whereas math theory and R says -10 %% 3 = 2.

Comment: What do you call a wrap-around ? An overflow of your addition ?

Comment: What do you mean by `modulo operation is signed` ?

Comment: '#include <stdio.h>

      int main(void) {
 int a = 3;
 int b = 10;
 int c = -7;
 int d = 0;
 
 d = (a+b)%c;
 
 printf("%d", d);
 
 return 0;
       }'

Gives 6 as expected.
For the "wrap around", I assume you talk about overflow. You can use Long if Int is too small, or check the values before operations.
For extra long values, libraries exists that handle such types, far beyond the possibilities of built-in C types.

Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @Dinesh  We talk about C use of the modulo operator here, and -10%3 is expected to be -1 : -10 / (3*(-3)) = -1.
I don't see how it could be 2.

Comment: @Tchou -10 = 2 + 3*(-4)

Comment: `((A % C) + (B % C)) % C` already takes care of the possible wrap-around of `A+B`.

Comment: @Tchou with a yardstick established, it ought to be much simplified. But a code like log(mod(a,b)) which worked in C might fail elsewhere.

Comment: In your unsigned example, the only reason you think that `(0xffffffff + 1) % 3 == 0` is because you are assuming that `0xffffffff + 1 == 0`, which is not correct, except when dealing with fixed-sized registers that truncate addition results. `0x100000000 % 3 == 1`, which is what you get when you do `((0xffffffff % 3) + (1 % 3)) % 3`...

Comment: I'm curious what you need this for. Usually people just choose C to be less than `2^31` so that `((A % C) + (B % C)) % C` always works. Then they ask about `A * B % C` which is a harder problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
((a+b)%2^n)%c
```

Let

```
a+b = k 2^n + d
```

Where `k = 0 or 1` and `d < 2^n`.

Plugging in you get:

```
 ((k 2^n + d) % 2^n) % c = (d % 2^n) % c = d % c
```

Taking the previous expression modulo `c` you get

```
 (a + b) % c = (k 2^n + d) % c => d % c = a % c + b % c - k 2^n % c
```

With `n = 32`, in C:

```
unsigned myMod(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c)
{
     // k = 1 if the sum overflows
     unsigned k = ( a > UINT_MAX - b or b > UINT_MAX - a);

     return ( a % c + b % c -  k*(UINT_MAX%c + 1))%c;
}

myMod(0x1U,0xFFFFFFFFU,0x3U) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In math, integer division is normally rounded down towards negative infinity, and the sign of modulo is the same as the same of the "divisor" or it's zero: -10 mod 3 = 2 and 10 mod -3 = -2 (quotient rounded down to -4). In C / C++, integer division is rounded towards zero and the sign of % is the same as the sign of the "dividend" or "numerator" or it's zero, -10 mod 3 = -1 and 10 mod -3 = 1 (quotient rounded towards zero to -3). When doing finite field type math with C / C++, you need to do post correction so that the results match the mathematical definition of modulo. For example, if X % 3 = -1, then add 3 so that X mod 3 = +2.

Assuming C is positive, then the mathematical field modulo C consists of the numbers {0, 1, ... C-1}, without any negative numbers. If C was negative (this is unusual for modulo), then the field is {0, -1, -2, ... C+1}. Assuming C is positive, then if A or B is negative, it is still safe to use ((A%C)+(B%C))%C, and then post correct if the result is negative by adding C to the result.

Comment: The problem is that integer addition inserts an implicit modulo due to it's truncation.

Comment: @rcgldr Could you please cite a reference to your definition? Modulus is supposedly a positive number.

Comment: @Dinesh - links: [wiki modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) - Note the definition by Knuth r = a - (floor(a/n) * n), where floor rounds down to negative infinity. [wiki prime field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Prime_fields) - Note that the elements of such a field are integers modulo p which are 0, ..., p-1 (no negative numbers for a positive p). [wiki modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) For languages like APL (from the 1960's) and Python, the modulo operator result has the same sign as the divisor (or it's zero).

Comment: @Dinesh - Continuing, note that the modulo function as defined in APL or Python is more mathematically consistent. Using integer math: rem = (a + m*b) % b , always returns the same result for any m, positive, zero, or negative. Also the range (image) of modulo is consistent regardless of the sign of the input (dividend or numerator), for positive b, it's {0, 1, ... , b-1} for negative b, it's {0, -1, ..., b+1}.

Comment: @rcgldr, Taking Knuth's defn, for a=-10 mod n=3. floor(a/n) = -4 as has been suggested, and -10 mod 3 is +2. (Also, every mod >= 0.) This does not jibe with what other commenters have suggested. R matches it, JavaScript does not and nor does C. So -- either some confusion or disagreement.

Comment: @Dinesh - The mathematical definition of modulo is consistent. Here is another link: [modulo](http://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/congruence-modulo). The implementation of modulo or remainder in programming languages varies, probably because integer division on many computers rounds towards zero instead of negative infinity. APL, a math oriented programming language from the early 1960's, and some other programming languages follow the mathematical definition of modulo, while C and some other languages do not.

Comment: @rcgldr you are right. I had a porting issue many years ago from R to C/C++ and was that so hard to find!

Comment: @rcgldr you are right. (Sorry, I had made a wrong recollection.)